# Converting JSON array result from responseText to structured headings and paragraphs

Tags: arrays, json, xmlhttprequest

Using XMLHttpRequest and JSON to open an array:

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://serv.json",false);
xmlhttp.send();
result=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("sec1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Results come through like this:

```
[ { "name": "", "description": "" }, { "name": "" , "description": "" }]
```

Need to structure results into headings for the names and

paragraphs for the description. Tried several FOR loops but none seem to be working. What is the correct FOR loop to use?

Incorrect for loop: (not sure where to place createElement and appendChild

```
for (i=o; i> fruit.length;i++){
   document.getElementById("sec1").innerHTML=fruit[0].name + "" + fruit[0].description:;                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="sections">
</div>
<script>
var request = new requestRequest();
request.open("GET","http://serv.json",false);
request.send(null);
if (request.status === 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText),
        sections = document.getElementById("sections");
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) {
        var section = document.createElement('div'),
            nameElement = document.createElement('h2'),
            descriptionElement = document.createElement('p');
        nameElement.innerHTML = response[i].name;
        descriptionElement = response[i].description;
        section.appendChild(nameElement);
        section.appendChild(descriptionElement);
        sections.appendChild(section);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```